# Passing third-party variables to contact form view

Tags: 8, emails

I am using the following modules provided by default from Drupal's core - `Contact` and `Contact Storage` to manage simple contact forms.

For my module, I needed to include a title and sub-title fields in my contact forms, so I decided that the approach taken in `Contact Storage` suits me the most and I did the following:

- In my `.module` file I implemented `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` like this - `module_form_contact_form_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {}` in which I placed my fields `$form['title']` and `$form['sub_title']`
- Then I added custom form builder function so that I can store my extra data using the functionality provided by `ThirdPartySettingInterface` like this `$form['#entity_builders'][] = 'module_contact_form_form_builder';`
- In my custom builder function I invoke only the method to store my custom data, like this: `$contact_form->setThirdPartySetting(/** **/);`

So far - so good. I can save and later on, edit the data, but there comes in my problem:

*How am I supposed to pass these two fields to my view/template?* I tried to look for some `_preprocess` hooks, but I don't know how to access the data stored by `ThirdPartySetting` outside of form scope.

I want to state that I am fairly new to Drupal development whatsoever, so any kind of advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You will have to create fields for the Contact storage entities I guess and see how `Contact storage` has done it, you will get a fair idea of how things are working

See `hook_entity_base_field_info()` in `contact_storage.module`